# Copying data in R dataframe from one cell to another based on contents of another cell

Tags: r, dataframe, copy-paste

Here's some example code to help everyone understand what I am trying to do here:

```
ID  PicName  Rating  Correct
1   flower   4       
1   Answer           1
2   cat      5       
2   Answer           1
```

What I'm trying to do is link up the "Answer" rows with the corresponding data in the row above them, then delete those "Answer" rows. So namely, I need the contents of the "Correct" column on "Answer" rows moved to the cell in the same column of the previous row. My instinct on this problem was initially to try to index those answer rows and search through the dataframe this way, but I'm not sure how to implement a command to take the data out of these specific cells and move it to other specific cells. Any insight on this problem would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the `data.table` package you can go through each `ID`, select the first value of `PicName` and `Rating`, and the second value of `Correct`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) # give df class "data.table"
df[, .( PicName = PicName[1] 
      , Rating  = Rating[1]
      , Correct = Correct[2])
   , by = ID]
```

Returns

```
   ID PicName Rating Correct
1:  1  flower      4       1
2:  2     cat      5       1
```

Another option is to `merge` the Answer rows with the others (gives same result)

```
setkey(df, ID)
merge(df[PicName != 'Answer', -'Correct']
      , df[PicName == 'Answer', .(ID, Correct)])
```

Data Used:

```
df <- fread( 
"ID  PicName  Rating  Correct
1   flower   4       NA
1   Answer   NA        1
2   cat      5       NA
2   Answer  NA         1")
```

===================

If you have more than one pair per `ID` group you can use the below code. This picks out rows where `PicName == 'Answer'` is `FALSE`, uses those rows for `PicName` and `Rating` columns, then uses the other rows for the `Correct` column.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(df) # give df class "data.table"

df[, (PicName == 'Answer') 
      %>% {.(PicName  = PicName[!.]
            , Rating  = Rating[!.]
            , Correct = Correct[.])}
   , by = ID]
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have been more clear: in the actual data I need to change, there are multiple observations for each participant ID. The by operator here is causing only the first observation for each ID to be kept.

Comment: @MattSabia Hard to say without seeing representative example data, but see my edit for a solution which could work.

Answer (score 1):

@Renu's approach is great, however, I prefer `dplyr` / `tidyverse`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(
    PicName = first(PicName),
    Rating = first(Rating),
    Correct = nth(Correct, 2))
```

returns:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
     ID PicName Rating Correct
  <int> <fct>    <int>   <int>
1     1 flower       4       1
2     2 cat          5       1
```

Pretty much the same thing though.